# Codename One: How to localize styled components

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to add an Arabic bundle using this code:

```
    resourceBudle = new HashMap<String, String>();
    resourceBudle.put("Ok", "موافق");
    resourceBudle.put("@rtl", "true");
    resourceBudle.put("MainTitle", "عربتي");
    UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(resourceBudle);
```

Now the MainTitle is a label which I have styled using a UIID in the theme designer. I have set font to large and alignment to center. Now when I try to create a form with a toolbar and set the titlecomponent of the tolbar to this label I dont get the Arabix text. Instead I get for each character a box with "X" inside it. It looks like there is an encoding issue but I am not sure why. Can You please help??!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok Sorry i think the problem was with the system font that I used. I had to change the font to monospace for example or any other font that supports Arabic.

Thanks.

Comment: Most regular fonts should work with Arabic, notice that the "on-device" fonts might differ from the ones in the simulator. You can also download free TTF fonts from the Google font project and use them in your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shai your very helpful